# shell script, how to escape variables?

Tags: shell, sed, escaping

I am writing a shell script where I input a value and want to use the value for some other commands. My problem is that I want to escape this value.

For example, if I input `http://example.com` in the following script

```
echo "Input a value for my_value"
read my_value

echo $my_value
```

It will result in `http://example.com`

But the result I wish is `http\:\/\/example\.com`

How do I achieve this?

The command I'm trying to run is

```
sed -i s/url/$my_value/g somefile.html
```

without the escape it becomes `sed -i s/url/http://example.com/g somefile.html` which obviously is a syntax error..

Comment: `my_value=${my_value//\/\//\\/\\/}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use other characters to split the `s` arguments. I like the `,`

```
sed -i 's,url,http://example.com,g'
```

. If you really want it you can use sed to replace the `/` in the argument, before executing

```
url=$(echo "http://example.com"|sed 's,/,\\/,g')
sed -i 's/url/'"$url"'/g' input
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to escape `/` in the variable, you can use an alternate regex delimiter in `sed`:

```
sed -i "s~url~$my_value~g" somefile.html
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a slash before any non-alphanumeric character:

```
$ my_value=http://example.com
$ my_value=$(sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\\&/g' <<<"$my_value")
$ echo "$my_value"
http\:\/\/example\.com
```

However, if you want to then use that in a sed command, you need to double the backslashes

```
$ echo this is the url here | sed "s#url#$my_value#g"
this is the http://example.com here
$ echo this is the url here | sed "s#url#${my_value//\\/\\\\}#g"
this is the http\:\/\/example\.com here
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you just want to replace one literal string with a different literal string but sed CANNOT operate on strings. See [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460) for a sed workaround but you might be better off just using a tool that can work with strings, e.g. awk:

```
awk -v old='original string' -v new='replacement string' '
    s=index($0,old) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)) }
    { print }
' file
```